# Infrared python

Tags: python, infrared

Could anyone point me in the direction of how I would go about controlling a television using python with an infrared sensor.  I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `pyLirc` here http://www.lirc.org/software.html.

and also do a quick search of keyword like `infrared , remote control` at [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

May be some of the results can help you.

Comment: ah i was 2 minutes too late :)

Answer (score 2):

You could look into [**pyLirc**](http://www.lirc.org/software.html).